# VScodeのssh秘密鍵のアドレス設定の変更ができるかどうか？

Tags: windows, vscode, ssh

VScodeを用いてssh接続を試みましたが，以下のようなエラーが出ました．

`no such identity: C:user\ユーザー名\.ssh\id_rsa: No such file or directory`

私はWSLを使用しており，秘密鍵の場所がWSLの.sshの場所にあります．

そこでVScodeの秘密鍵のアドレスをWindowsのユーザーからWSLの秘密鍵のアドレスに変更したいと思っているのですが，どなたか存じておりますでしょうか．

ご返信頂けましたら幸いです．何卒宜しくお願い致します．

Comment: explorerの左ペインの下にLinuxの項目があります、そこがwslの場所なのでここから秘密鍵のパスをコピーできませんか？

Comment: ~/.ssh/configに必要な設定を書く。

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません．ありがとうございます．explorerの左ペインを調べましたが，Linuxは存在していませんでした．ちなみにWSLのパスは`C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04\LocalState\rootfs\home\WSLユーザー名`となっております

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode は使用していないので、あくまで検索して出てきた情報を元に回答しています。

---

恐らく 拡張機能の Remote Development をインストールしているものと思われますが、コマンドパレットから「Remote - SSH:Editing Configuration Files」を選択して設定ファイルを開きます。

以下のような書式でリモートホスト毎の設定が記述されていると思うので、`IdentityFile` で秘密鍵のパスを変更してみてください。

```
Host your-remote-server
    HostName your-remote-server.example.com
    User your.name
    IdentityFile C:\Users\your\secret\key\path\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Comment: ご返信頂きありがとうございます．現時点の状況ですが，IdentityFileの中身を`C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04\LocalState\rootfs\home\WSLユーザー名/.ssh/id_rsa`と設定しておりましたが，WARNINGとエラーが出てしまいます．また以下のURLの方法で試しましたが同じ結果になりました．https://qiita.com/yumenomatayume/items/552b1a4406e85df306c4　引き続き設定をしていきたいと思っております

Comment: お世話になっております．Cドライブ下にWSL下の秘密鍵のシンボリックリンクを作成したところ，何とか繋がりました．改めてお礼申し上げます．